# Como instalar numpy e outros módulos?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip

Preciso de ajuda como instalar numpy. Tentei instalar pygame usando pip mas não resultou e fiquei confusa em como installar modulos ou packages.

Uso python 3.5.0 em Windows 10 pro

Answer (score 1):

1. Instale [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html)
2. Na linha de comandos, escreva: `$ conda install numpy`

Com isso provavelmente você conseguirá todas as livrarias e pacotes. O Anaconda incluí 125 pacotes.

Comment: Diz: SintaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: $ conda install numpy

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente para se instalar o pygame não á necessidade de o fazer usando o pip pois o mesmo pode ser baixado via site oficial [aqui](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml), baixe a versão utilizando opção recomendada pelo próprio site, ou seja, para o OS que você usa que no caso e windows, quanto a instalar numpy, vou te dar duas opções.

### 1° opção

baixe o mesmo neste [link](https://github.com/pypa/pip), *extraia o pacote baixado*, via prompt navegue ate a pasta aonde se encontra o mesmo e faça o seguinte:

```
python setup.py build
```

depois

```
python setup.py install
```

#### instalando o numpy

apos ter instalado o pip, execute o seguinte comando via prompt:

```
pip install numpy
```

### 2° opção

outra opção para a instalação do numpy e utilizando o executável do mesmo que se encontra [bem aqui](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/).

baixe a versão mais atual e instale normalmente.

Comment: setup.py build  do numy --- no WIndows?? Build implica em compilar os módulos em C, isso em geral exige toda uma cadeia de software - compilador, ferramentas auxiliares, etc... - tem que estar numa máquina ja configurada com isso tudo pra funcionar.